# Best practice using finally? (Not for releasing resources)

Tags: java, finally

To start; just because one *can* do it doesn't always means one *should* do it.  I'll use a code snippet to explain my question:

```
private StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); //Using StringBuffer because it is thread safe

... /*append to sb in methods etc*/ ...

public String getSbValue() {
    try {
        return sb.toString();
    } finally {
        sb = new StringBuffer(); //or sb.delete(0, sb.length()); ?
    }
}
```

**Is this a good or bad practice or neither?**

Or should I rather do:

```
public String getSbValue() {
    String ret = sb.toString();
    sb = new StringBuffer(); //or sb.delete(0, sb.length()); ?
    return ret;
}
```

Best regards,

André

Comment: `sb = new StringBuffer();` - what are you trying to accomplish using this statement in the `finally`?

Comment: This is clearly highly subjective. I personally find the logic of this very short method hard to follow.

Comment: @R.J.: I'm trying to clear the StringBuffer after I returned the value.

Comment: @NPE: What about processing? That is will this use more processing / resources?

Comment: BTW name of your method `getSbValue()` is fairly misleading, name should specify that `sb` value will be cleared after method call

Comment: @zvdh I agree, it was just a quick code snippet.  The actual variable has a more descriptive name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly highly subjective. I personally find the logic of the very short method using `finally` hard to follow.

To my eye, the following is clearer:

```
public String getSbValue() {
    StringBuffer prev_sb = sb;
    sb = new StringBuffer();
    return prev_sb.toString();
}
```

(Your second example, while being similar to my code above is different, and has different semantics to your first example.)

P.S. You should almost certainly be using `StringBuilder` in place of `StringBuffer`.

Comment: Does it use less resources to create a StringBuffer/StringBuilder than a String?
StringBuffer is used because it is Thread Safe and this function is in a very "threaded" environment :) - Else I always use StringBuilder.

Comment: @TungstenX: using `StringBuffer` does *not* make your code thread-safe! `StringBuffer` implements each of its methods in a thread-safe manner, but since your code consists of multiple method invocations on the `StringBuffer` without any synchronization, your code still lacks thread-safety.

Answer (score 1):

I think option 1 for some programmers will look like a puzzle. Option 2 is shorter and clearer

Comment: Thank you for the response. I agree it is subjective, just wanted to know if there is something wrong in using it like this, that is, it uses way more processing/resources etc.